# jQuery expand DIV horizontaly on click and replace content

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, expandable

I'm struggling to get this http://jsfiddle.net/L5P2Y/ to work horizontal and not vertical.

I have task list on right side, when I click on div (containing task info) I would like that 'task list' shrinks from 100% to 70% width , other 30% will take new div with comments (or other content).  This is my html/css [http://jsfiddle.net/WZLHm/](http://jsfiddle.net/WZLHm/1/)
[image: sketch]

```
<style>
.task{background:blue;width:70%;float:left;color:white;}
.task a{color:white;}
.content{background:red; width:30%; float:left;}
</style>
<div class="task">        
    <h6>This div shrinks from 100% to 70% width when user clicks on any of links</h6>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First task</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second task</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third task</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content that will be replaced on each click
</div>
```

Comment: where is the js you tried to use?

Comment: fiddle doesn't have any js in it

Comment: I've updated my question with JS (updated jsfiddle)

Comment: you need to animate the height: http://jsfiddle.net/WZLHm/2/

Comment: Tnx @JayLane I've updated [http://jsfiddle.net/WZLHm/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/WZLHm/3/) . I wasn't clear at the beginning. 
If I have three links, that means that I also have three different content boxes... how to show  the right content box.